# BluetoothSocket as global variable crashes

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, global-variables

I have created a class that should let me use a Bluetooth Socket as a global variable

```
package com.lorenzo.robo_so;

  import android.app.Application;
  import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

  public class Roboso extends Application {

  private BluetoothSocket Socket;

  @Override
   public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
   }

  public BluetoothSocket getState(){
    return Socket;
  }
  public void setState(BluetoothSocket s){
      Socket = s;
  }
}
```

unfortunately, when i try to change the global variable after a connection made in the mainactivity the app crashes

here is the class where i make the connection:

```
public Roboso application = (Roboso) this.getApplication();
```

,

```
public class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connessione...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... add) {

        moduloBT.cancelDiscovery();
        BluetoothDevice device = moduloBT.getRemoteDevice(add[0]);
        String name = device.getName();
        try {
          SocketBT = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Errore di connessione", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            SocketBT.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          try {
              SocketBT.close();
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Errore di connessione", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } catch (IOException e2) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Errore di connessione", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
        application.setState(SocketBT);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IPWebcam.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, name);
        startActivity(intent);
        return name;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String name){
        finish();
    }
}
```

this class works properly when i delete the command `application.setState(SocketBT);` but i don't understand why there is a problem using a bluetoothsocket as a global variable

This is the log after the crash:

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): Process: com.lorenzo.robo_so, PID: 24837

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at com.lorenzo.robo_so.MainActivity$Connection.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:247)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at com.lorenzo.robo_so.MainActivity$Connection.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

07-21 13:02:44.505: E/AndroidRuntime(24837): ... 4 more

07-21 13:02:48.755: I/Process(24837): Sending signal. PID: 24837 SIG: 9

Comment: How does the log say it crashed?